# Conversion of String-Types

Tags: c++, c++builder

There are a lot of string-types in C++: WideString, UnicodeString, String, wstring, string, AnsiString, Variant

In my code are a lot of conversions like

```
WideString s1 = UnicodeString ( wstring(s2.str().c_str()).c_str()).c_str();
```

This is in one word : confusing!

Is there a simple way to handle all the string-conversions with one helper-class never thinking again about how to convert one string-type into an other one like:

```
s1 = sc(s2);    // sc = string-converter
```

or

```
sc(s1,s2);      // s1 = convert to, s2 = convert from
```

Comment: Please explain what are WideString, UnicodeString, AnsiString and String. These are certainly not classes in C++ standard library. C++/CLI maybe? Also, Variant is a type specific for WINAPI, not C++.

Comment: I am using C++ Builder XE7.

Comment: Did you try to create the template function for conversion in a way that user Do Re suggested before accepting his answer? His implementation only has one template parameter, he is literally suggesting you cast the type into itself (from T to T)?!

Comment: I had noticed the mistake. The error was not important for me, only the approach. He showed me the right direction and this was the solution or inspiration. The rest is a matter of my own fantasy and transpiration.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. I understand that it did not matter that much to you. However, someone with less experience than you will look at this question, see that as accepted answer and then wonder why is it not working. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `String` or `AnsiString`. Those are replaced by `UnicodeString`.  The `WideString` is a wrapper for COM BSTR - it should only be used when you are accessing a COM interface.

Comment: thank's. AnsiString is a relict of Delphi and is definied as template shaping of AnsiStringT.

Comment: `WideString`, `UnicodeString`, `AnsiString`, and `Variant` (`String` is just an alias for `AnsiString` or `UnicodeString` depending on C++Builder version) are all assignment compatible with each other.  You don't need manual conversions for them, just assign them directly to each other as needed.  You only need to use `c_str()` when converting to/from `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a wrapper class that will handle all possible conversions. You can use
a template class but please note that you will have to make additional template
specializations because most of these conversions cannot be expressed in a
generic way. For instance, you can easily convert from `WideString` to `UnicodeString`
with casting but you cannot simply cast `wstring` to `string`. For types that 
can be cast, you can use generic part:

```
template <class TypeFrom, class TypeTo>
TypeTo convert(const TypeFrom &from)
{
    return static_cast<TypeTo>(from);
}
```

but this will not work for conversion of `wstring` to `string`. You need a template
specialization for that:

```
template <>
std::string convert<std::wstring, std::string>(const std::wstring &from)
{
    return std::string(from.begin(), from.end());
}
```

It is impossible to list all combinations here, you will have to take care of that. Here
is link that can help with some conversions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments I decided to use overloading functions!

If I use templates my code looks like this:

```
string  s = convert<wstring,string> (wstring(L"hello"));
```

The Problem is that I have to write the types I want to convert. Why should I do that? The compiler knows the types!

If I use overloading functions

```
std::string convert(const std::wstring &from)
{
  return std::string(from.begin(), from.end());
}

std::wstring convert(const std::string &from)
{
  return std::wstring(from.begin(), from.end());
}
```

my code looks so:

```
string str2 = convert(wstring(L"hello"));
```

And that's the way I like it: never repeat myself. be lazy. be simple as possible. ^^

Comment: Oh no, the overloading function has a limitation! "char     f1(double);
string   f1(double);" is not allowed "Redeklaration of f1 with another type"-error occures!

Answer (score 1):

This is my current solution of the conversion problematic

```
std::string convert1(const std::wstring &from) {
  return std::string(from.begin(), from.end()); }

std::string convert1(const UnicodeString &from) {        // String = UnicodeString
  wstring strTemp = from.c_str();
  return std::string(strTemp.begin(), strTemp.end()); }

std::string convert1(const WideString &from) {
  wstring strTemp = from.c_bstr();
  return std::string(strTemp.begin(), strTemp.end()); }


std::wstring convert2(const std::string &from) {
  return std::wstring(from.begin(), from.end()); }

std::wstring convert2(const UnicodeString &from) {
  wstring strTemp = from.c_str();
  return std::wstring(strTemp.begin(), strTemp.end()); }

std::wstring convert2(const WideString &from) {
  wstring strTemp = from.c_bstr();
  return std::wstring(strTemp.begin(), strTemp.end()); }


UnicodeString convert3(const std::string &from) {
  wstring strTemp(from.begin(), from.end());
  return UnicodeString(strTemp.c_str()); }

UnicodeString convert3(const std::wstring &from) {
  return UnicodeString(from.c_str()); }

UnicodeString convert3(const WideString &from) {
  return UnicodeString(from.c_bstr()); }


WideString convert4(const std::string &from) {
  wstring strTemp(from.begin(), from.end());
  return WideString(strTemp.c_str()); }

WideString convert4(const std::wstring &from) {
  return WideString(from.c_str()); }

WideString convert4(const UnicodeString &from) {
  return WideString(from.c_str()); }



wchar_t* convert5(const std::string &from) {
  static wstring strTemp;
  strTemp.clear();
  strTemp.assign(from.begin(), from.end());
  return (wchar_t*) strTemp.c_str(); }

wchar_t* convert5(const std::wstring &from) {
  return (wchar_t*) from.c_str(); }

wchar_t* convert5(const UnicodeString &from) {
  return from.c_str(); }

wchar_t* convert5(const WideString &from) {
  return from.c_bstr(); }
```

Usage:

```
  std::string   s1  = convert1 (wstring       (L"Hallo1" ));
  std::string   s2  = convert1 (UnicodeString (L"Hallo2" ));
  std::string   s3  = convert1 (WideString    (L"Hallo3" ));
  std::wstring  s4  = convert2 (std::string   ( "Hallo4" ));
  std::wstring  s5  = convert2 (UnicodeString (L"Hallo5" ));
  std::wstring  s6  = convert2 (WideString    (L"Hallo6" ));
  UnicodeString s7  = convert3 (std::string   ( "Hallo7" ));
  UnicodeString s8  = convert3 (std::wstring  (L"Hallo8" ));
  UnicodeString s9  = convert3 (WideString    (L"Hallo9" ));
  WideString    s10 = convert4 (std::string   ( "Hallo10"));
  WideString    s11 = convert4 (std::wstring  (L"Hallo11"));
  WideString    s12 = convert4 (UnicodeString (L"Hallo12"));

  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s1));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s2));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s3));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s4));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s5));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s6));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s7));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s8));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s9));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s10));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s11));
  Memo->Lines->Add(convert5(s12));
```

Result:

```
Hallo1
Hallo2
Hallo3
Hallo4
Hallo5
Hallo6
Hallo7
Hallo8
Hallo9
Hallo10
Hallo11
Hallo12
```

Comment: These convert functions have a problem, they lose information when converting down.  Consider whether you want to use UTF-8 in your `std::string`s

Comment: yes, you'r right if the stored text has significant multi-bytes.

Comment: I just thought of that I can expand my functions with the set of text-streams...^^ By the way I shorted the name from "convert" to "SC" (String Convert).

Comment: UTF-8 is a separat story... I found this site to handle text coded in UTF-8 : http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: oh, good to know! thank's again!^^ http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/UTF-8_Conversion_Routines

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly old-style C89-C99 user, thus I can suggest using some macros. Of cours as alredy suggested, templates will be **much** more elegant and safe (since will be compiler-traced for errors), but just make your weapon od choice.

`#define CONV_TO_WSTRING(s1) ( wstring(s1.str().c_str()).c_str()).c_str()`

for instance.

Then in usage you have:

`s1 = CONV_TO_WSTRING(s2);`

Answer (score -1):

Make your own [template class](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html) with all possible conversions.

Inside your template you should use a typesafe cast, such as [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Then it is only one time confusing...

**EDIT**

Maybe it could be something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T convert(T x)
{
  T value;
  value = static_cast<T>(x);
  return value;
}
```

(I did not enter the implementation as these are variable types I do not know. This is the way I would try to do this)

Comment: This answer is of very poor quality as it is. Most of these conversions cannot be performed by doing a cast. Please update the answer with more information on how to implement this class.

Comment: I agree with you. This post IS of very poor quality, just as the question is. To make a more detailed showcase of how to do this, I would need to get more information about the types used above